# Newly added item is not being displayed on the screen in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have written a simple code in ReactJS in which I am calling View component from Store component by passing state's data and updateState function as props. View component then calls Action component by passing the same two props. And Action component modifies the state of Store component and calls its function updateState to modify the state.

Now the problem is that the newly added item is not being displayed in the list visible on the screen. And also I am getting an error (given below). So please tell what is the problem in my code?

**Error:**

```
index.js:1017 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `View`. See fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
    in li (created by View)
    in View (created by Store)
    in div (created by Store)
    in Store
```

**Store.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import View from './View.jsx';

class Store extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: 
         [
            {
               name: 'First',
               id: 1
            },

            {
               name: 'Second',
               id: 2
            },

            {
               name: 'Third',
               id: 3
            }
         ]
      }

      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
   };

    updateState(newState) {
      this.setState({data: newState});
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
           <View storeData={this.state.data} func={this.updateState} />
         </div>
      );
   }
};

export default Store;
```

**View.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Action from './Action.jsx';

class View extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
                {this.props.storeData.map((eachObject) => (
                    <li key={eachObject.id}>{eachObject.name}</li>))}
            </ul>
            <Action storeData={this.props.storeData} func={this.props.func} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default View;
```

**Action.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

let itemIndex=3;

class Action extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.updateStore = this.updateStore.bind(this);
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <input type="text" ref="input"/>
            <button onClick={this.updateStore}>Add</button>
         </div>
      );
   };

   updateStore(e) {
        const node = this.refs.input;
        const text = node.value.trim();
        node.value = '';
        node.focus();

        ++itemIndex;
        var newItem = {itemIndex, text};
        var storeData = this.props.storeData;
        storeData.push(newItem);

        this.props.func(storeData);
    }
}

export default Action;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not setting the `id` or `name` properties:

```
var newItem = {
  id: itemIndex,
  name: text
};
var storeData = this.props.storeData;
storeData.push(newItem);
```

**See here for working example:**

```js
let itemIndex=3;

class Action extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.updateStore = this.updateStore.bind(this);
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <input type="text" ref="input"/>
            <button onClick={this.updateStore}>Add</button>
         </div>
      );
   };

   updateStore(e) {
        const node = this.refs.input;
        const text = node.value.trim();
        node.value = '';
        node.focus();

        ++itemIndex;
        var newItem = {
          id: itemIndex,
          name: text
        };
        var storeData = this.props.storeData;
        storeData.push(newItem);

        this.props.func(storeData);
    }
}

class View extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
                {this.props.storeData.map((eachObject) => (
                    <li key={eachObject.id}>{eachObject.name}</li>))}
            </ul>
            <Action storeData={this.props.storeData} func={this.props.func} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Store extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: 
         [
            {
               name: 'First',
               id: 1
            },
            {
               name: 'Second',
               id: 2
            },
            {
               name: 'Third',
               id: 3
            }
         ]
      }

      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
   };

    updateState(newState) {
      this.setState({data: newState});
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
           <View storeData={this.state.data} func={this.updateState} />
         </div>
      );
   }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Store />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: the problem was the `id` but also the `name` property, please see my edit